# Using Net::OpenSSH::rsync_get() method as sudo

Tags: perl

I'm using the [`Net::OpenSSH`](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.74/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm) module to download a directory using the `rsync_get` method. Some of the files in the directory don't allow the user I'm logged in as to read some of the files and so they can't be downloaded. Can anyone suggest a workaround for this? Is there some way to run this method with the `sudo` command?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 on this page worked for me: https://crashingdaily.wordpress.com/2007/06/29/rsync-and-sudo-over-ssh/

Summary:

Option 1. Set NOPASSWD in the /etc/sudoers file.

crashingdaily ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync
Then use the --rsync-path option to specify the sudo wrapper.

rsync -a -e "ssh" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" crashingdaily@server.remotehost.com:/u02/data_pump_dir/ /archive

Answer (score 0):

If your `sudo` is configurred to NOT ask for a password, you can do as in your post:

```
$ssh->rsync_get({rsync_path => 'sudo rsync'}, ...);
```

On the other hand, if `sudo` requires a password for running commands as root, I think the easiest way is to use a wrapper script as the following, for sending the password to `sudo`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# save me as ~/bin/sudo_rsync on the target machine

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Pty;

my $passwd = 's3cr3t';

my $pty = IO::Pty->new;
my $pid = fork;
unless ($pid) {
    defined $pid or die "unable to fork";
    $pty->make_slave_controlling_terminal;
    do { exec 'sudo', 'rsync', @ARGV };
    exit -1;
}

print {$pty} "$passwd\n";
waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Then, from the local machine...

```
$ssh->rsync_get({rsync_path => '~/bin/sudo_rsync'},
                '/etc/shadow', '/tmp/shadow');
```

Obviously, having the password hard-coded in the script is a very bad idea... but it also is a bad idea to pass it on the command line or in an environment variable. I don't think there is a nice solution for this problem other than avoiding having `sudo` ask for the password on things you want to automate on the first place!

Another ugly solution that works when sudo is configured to cache credentials for a while (passing the password on the command line):

```
$ssh->rsync_get( { rsync_path =>
                   'sudo -k && ' .
                   'echo s3cr3t|sudo -Sp "" cat /dev/null && ' .
                   'sudo -Sp "" rsync' },
                 "/etc/shadow", "/tmp/shadow" );
```